# Conditional variable assignment operator portability?

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment

According to make's [Setting Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Setting), I can conditionally assign to a undefined variable with:

```
FOO ?= bar
```

Is the operator portable? Can it be used on non-GNU systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is not defined in the POSIX standard for make, so it won't be available in versions of make other than GNU make.  Of course, GNU make is itself portable, so it can and very often is used on non-GNU systems, so in that sense it is portable to non-GNU systems :-).

Comment: Thanks MadScientist. Would you happen to know about the alternative `ifeq ($(origin FOO), undefined)`?

Comment: `ifeq`, `define`, etc. are also GNU make-only facilities.  All the preprocessor operations with the exception of `include` are extra features.  The standard for `make` is extremely anemic when it comes to power and flexibility; that's probably why (as far as I'm aware) there's not a single `make` program out there that implements exactly the standard with no additional features.  It's also why one of my personal `make` rules is, _don't bother writing portable makefiles, use a portable `make` instead_.